# Deploying django on Heroku : Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured

Tags: django, heroku

I have a django app that runs perfectly locally, but when I try to deploy it on heroku I continue to run into this error,

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This is my settings file,

```
import os
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = *****

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com', ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'aggregator',
    'bouncer',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'bouncer.User'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'verification@sampleapp.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '####'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.ftb_core_api.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sampleapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sampleapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', ''),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', ''),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS', ''),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# for dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# REST Framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    )
}
```

This is my wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ftb_core_backend.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

So clearly my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is defined.

I cant find the line that calls LOGGING_COFIG that throws up the error.Neither do I have any idea where settings,config() is being called.

Here's the full stack trace,

`` Starting process with command `gunicorn ftb_core_backend.wsgi —-log-file -`
2018-02-28T17:56:52.287605+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-28 17:56:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2018-02-28T17:56:52.288193+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-28 17:56:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:58538 (4)
2018-02-28T17:56:52.288393+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-28 17:56:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-02-28T17:56:52.295020+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-28 17:56:52 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-02-28T17:56:52.390046+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-28 17:56:52 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-02-28T17:56:52.832612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-02-28T17:56:53.050445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796081+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-28 17:56:52 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796116+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796118+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796120+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796121+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796123+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796125+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796126+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796128+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796129+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796131+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796132+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796134+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796136+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796137+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796139+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796142+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796140+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/ftb_core_backend/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796144+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796145+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796147+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796148+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796150+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796152+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup(name)
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796154+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796155+00:00 app[web.1]:     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
2018-02-28T17:56:52.796203+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings. ``

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. What command are you running when you see this error?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've updated the question with the relevant details.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show your ftb_core_backend.wsgi file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yup it's there already.

Comment: if your wsgi file is correctly copied, then your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not defined for the first call to get_wsgi_application (you have duplicated code).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not completely sure what you mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Got it

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks that was the exact problem. I removed the duplicate code and it worked like a charm. If you wanna put this as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Are you replying to me or Daniel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normally happens when you don't have the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable defined.

In this case your `.wsgi` file contains:

```
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ftb_core_backend.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

and the error is coming from the first line's call to `get_wsgi_application()` which doesn't have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` defined in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when setting the environment.

My solution is to open the terminal and set the environment manually

Here are the steps:(for mac)

1. open the terminal and type vim ~/.bash_profile
2. add below lines:

   ```
   PATH=${PATH}:/Users/work/workspace/[virtual_environment]/bin
   PYTHONPATH=${PATH}:/Users/work/PycharmProjects/[project_name]
   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=[project_name].settings
   ```
3. type `:wq` to save and exit terminal
4. type source ~/.bash_profile to reload it